# Skip nulls when unmarshalling JSON array into slice of pointers

Tags: json, go, null, slice, unmarshalling

I have following struct:

```golang
type Item struct {
    Id       string     `json:"id"`
    Name     string     `json:"name"`
    Products []*Product `json:"products"`
}

func (i *Item) Transform(input []byte) error {
    return json.Unmarshal(input, i)
}
```

I have to perform several operations on `Products` and it's members and it's nested members as well which for instance are `[]*Variant{}` or `[]*Shipping{}` etc.

Because most of slices in `Item` struct are slice of pointers, my code to process this data looks like this:

```golang
for _, product := range i.Products {
    if product == nil {
        continue
    }
    
    for _, variant := range product.Variants {
        if variant == nil {
            continue
        }
        
        for _, shipping := range shippings {
            if shipping == nil {
                continue
            }
      
            // and so on...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to mimick `omitempty` on `nil` values in slice of pointers? Example below.

JSON input:

```json
{
    "products": [
        null,
        {},
        null
    ]
}
```

output, equivalent to:

```golang
input := Item{
    Products: []Product{ {} }, // without nulls
}
```

I tried to use `omitempty` on `[]*Property` but it doesn't work. I also tried to use non-pointer values but then Go initialises every null to default struct value.

Comment: FYI `omitempty` applies ONLY to *encoding* (i.e. marshaling). It has no effect on decoding (i.e. unmarshaling).

Comment: mikolaj please see the updated answer for a suggestion (made by [blackgreen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4108803/blackgreen)) on how to avoid having to implement the custom unmarshaling for every slice type that is suspect to contain nulls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement a custom [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.18.2#Unmarshaler).

```golang
type Item struct {
    Id       string      `json:"id"`
    Name     string      `json:"name"`
    Products ProductList `json:"products"`
}

// Use []*Product if you intend to modify
// the individual elements in the slice.
// Use []Product if the elements are read-only.
type ProductList []*Product

// Implememt the json.Unmarshaler interface.
// This will cause the encoding/json decoder to
// invoke the UnmarshalJSON method, instead of
// performing the default decoding, whenever it
// encounters a ProductList instance.
func (ls *ProductList) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // first, do a normal unmarshal
    pp := []*Product{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &pp); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // next, append only the non-nil values
    for _, p := range pp {
        if p != nil {
            *ls = append(*ls, p)
        }
    }

    // done
    return nil
}
```

---

Credit to [@blackgreen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4108803/blackgreen):

With Go1.18 and up, you don't have to implement the custom unmarshaling for the other `[]*Variant{}` and `[]*Shipping{}` types. Instead you can use a slice type with a type parameter for the element.

```golang
type SkipNullList[T any] []*T

func (ls *SkipNullList[T]) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    pp := []*T{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &pp); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for _, p := range pp {
        if p != nil {
            *ls = append(*ls, p)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

type Item struct {
    Id       string                `json:"id"`
    Name     string                `json:"name"`
    Products SkipNullList[Product] `json:"products"`
}

type Product struct {
    // ...
    Variants SkipNullList[Variant] `json:"variants"`
}

type Variant struct {
    // ...
    Shippings SkipNullList[Shipping] `json:"shippings"`
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/az_9Mb_RBKX

Comment: @readers: here on SO and elsewhere you may find advice against using generics with JSON unmarshalling because type parameters must be known at compile-time. However in this case the invariant holds because the generic slice is supposed to be always instantiated with a concrete type upon usage as a struct field

Comment: Any idea of how to do this for YAML?

Comment: @Andy it would be pretty much the same thing but instead of implementing json.Unmarshaler you'd implement yaml.Unmarshaler.

Comment: @Andy https://go.dev/play/p/6OplJxmNH18